# Why are the errors reported by Coverity with version 7.7 and 2020.12 different for same code-base?

Tags: static, analysis, coverity

I am working on migration of Coverity server where Coverity has versions 7.7 and 2020.12 on old and new servers.

I can see that Coverity is reporting different errors for same code-base on these 2 Coverity servers. Most of the errors are common for both the servers, but there some errors which are not reported by latest version of Coverity (v 2020.12) but reported earlier (by Coverity version 7.7), and vice-versa.

How to decide if the new Coverity server is reporting legitimate errors?
Also want to know what kind of differences we can see if coverity version is different and what is the reason for such differences?

Comment: You will have to go over the errors being reported, that are different, and decide if it's a legitimate problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**. How do we decide if the new Coverity is reporting legitimate errors?

You have to inspect the differences individually to see if each one is a false positive (incorrect) or true positive (correct).  If there are too many to do so in a reasonable time, sample them at random to get a statistical estimate.  Be aware that accurately inspecting static analysis findings is time-consuming; I usually budget 5-10 minutes for each one.

**Q2**. What kind of differences we can see if the Coverity version is different?

It's not really possible to state any limit on the qualitative kinds of differences that may appear.

Quantitatively, historically at least, the Coverity developers attempt to ensure that there is no more than 5% "churn", where churn is defined as:

```
  new false positives + lost true positives
  -----------------------------------------
           number of old findings
```

This 5% rule is applied to successive major releases.  The churn when upgrading past multiple major releases can be higher.

There is no bound on the number of new true positives or lost false positives.

**Q3**. What is the reason for such differences?

The Coverity tool is continually being developed, with the intention (among other goals) of finding more true positives and fewer false positives.  To the extent this intention is realized, the new results should be "better" (overall more accurate) than the old.

However, as with any piece of software, mistakes may be made (or intentional tradeoffs made) that result in less accurate results in some cases.

Aside from these general statements, the release notes may have additional details about what has changed.